# How do I run the Scala tar file deployment created by Gradle without extracting?

Tags: scala, gradle

I have a Scala project using Gradle generated using `gradle init`.

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Scala application project to get you started.
 * For more details on building Java & JVM projects, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/userguide/building_java_projects.html in the Gradle documentation.
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the scala Plugin to add support for Scala.
    id 'scala'

    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application in Java.
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    // Use Maven Central for resolving dependencies.
    maven { }
}

dependencies {
    // Use Scala 2.13 in our library project
    implementation 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.13.11'
    implementation 'com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core:4.17.0'
    implementation 'com.datastax.oss:java-driver-query-builder:4.17.0'
    implementation 'com.datastax.oss:java-driver-mapper-runtime:4.17.0'

    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:32.1.1-jre'

    // Use Scalatest for testing our library
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation 'org.scalatest:scalatest_2.13:3.2.16'
    testImplementation 'org.scalatestplus:junit-4-13_2.13:3.2.2.0'

    // Need scala-xml at test runtime
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.13:1.2.0'

}

// Apply a specific Java toolchain to ease working on different environments.
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}

application {
    mainClass = 'jrg.test.App'
}
```

I can run it using `gradle run` and when I run `gradle build` I see the distribution getting created as a tar with the dependencies. If I just run `gradle jar` the dependencies don't show up in the jar. So now that I have the tar I would like to run it. I know I could extract and run but I would presume there is a way to run it as a tar.

Does anyone know how I could run the tar or zip directly? Can I configure to have it generate the tar as a jar?

if I extract the jar and run app/bin/app.sh it does work but extracting is super annoying and this seems like a solved problem.

Comment: I think you're looking for what is called a "fat jar", or "Uber jar" which will contain all dependencies + your code and resources. Keep in mind that even though it may be easier to run, it also has drawbacks.